# Doctrine2: Double relation to 1 entity

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have 2 entities: Album and AlbumImages. I've made annotations like this:

```
Entity\Album 
    /**
     *
     * @var Collection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumImages", mappedBy="album", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $images;

Entity\AlbumImages
    /**
     *
     * @var Album $album
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="images")
     */
    protected $album;
```

It works as expected. Each Album have a collection of images. If I remove Album, all Images are remove also.

Now I try to add cove to the Album. Cover can be one of the Album images.
Annotation looked like this:

```
Entity\Album
    /**
     * @var Image $image
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AlbumImages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
protected $thumb;
```

As a result Album now have cover (Entity\AlbumImages) and it works fine, **except** the delete of Album.

I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM album WHERE id = ?' with params [3]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fs2`.`album_images`, CONSTRAINT `FK_326483DD1137ABCF` FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `album` (`id`))
```

Can you point me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you are trying to remove the `Album` while there are still images attached to it.  The `@OneToMany` you have setup has cascade options, so if you remove the `Album`, the entries there go with it.  There is no such cascade on your `$thumb` attribute, so if it is set, an album image will remain and not get deleted.  Try setting the `$thumb` to `NULL` before the removal.

Comment: Setting $thumb to null works of course. But is this the only right way? I've tried to setup cascade options for $thumb, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Generally, yes you do have to ensure you cleanly remove all references when performing a removal.  The `orphanRemoval` system is designed as an assistant to pick up elements that no longer have any connection, if a connection persists, then so does the element.  Usually you would write a removal handler that performs the housekeeping at the same time as performing the primary removal task.